# use ascii code, 'a', 'b', 'c' -> octal , decimal, hexadecimal number

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

use ASCII code, 'a', 'b', 'c' -> octal , decimal, hexadecimal number
a,b,c's ASCII code value->print with octal, decimal, hexadecimal number.

Comment: Nah - I'll stick to Engish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


int main() 
{
    for ( int c : { 'a', 'b', 'c' } )
    {
        std::cout << std::oct << c << ' ' 
                  << std::dec << c << ' ' 
                  << std::hex << c << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
141 97 61
142 98 62
143 99 63
```

It is the same if to write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char c = 'c';

    std::cout << std::oct << ( int )a << ' ' 
              << std::dec << ( int )a << ' ' 
              << std::hex << ( int )a << std::endl; 

    std::cout << std::oct << ( int )b << ' ' 
              << std::dec << ( int )b << ' ' 
              << std::hex << ( int )b << std::endl; 

    std::cout << std::oct << ( int )c << ' ' 
              << std::dec << ( int )c << ' ' 
              << std::hex << ( int )c << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

In C the code can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char c = 'c';

    printf( "%o %d %x\n", a, a, a );    
    printf( "%o %d %x\n", b, b, b );    
    printf( "%o %d %x\n", c, c, c );    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm so glad to get some good example
but now I'm programming with C, not C++
So can I ask for C?